# Solving an indefinite integral: $\int{\frac{dx}{\sin^2(x)+5\cos^2(x)}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to solve and indefinite integral: $$\int{\frac{dx}{\sin^2x+5\cos^2x}}.$$
The only method that can be used is $u$-substitution.

The only thing I've done so far is that I've tried modifying it so there is either only $\sin^2x$ or $\cos^2x$ left, so we get the following two integrals, respectively:
$$\int{\frac{dx}{5-4\sin^2x}}$$
$$\int{\frac{dx}{1+4\cos^2x}}.$$

How would you go about finishing this problem using any of these two paths.

My question was deleted for being a duplicate of a question of solving and indefinite integral: $$\int{\frac{dx}{1+\sin^4x}}$$ which it obviously isn't.

Comment: $u=\tan(x/2).$.

Comment: Try multiplying numerator and denominator by sec^2(X) and take tanx as u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The go-to is often the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution), $u=\tan(x/2)$. This can be clunky, but it is effective for rational functions of sine and cosine.

---

A slightly more pleasant starting route can be achieved with

$$I := \int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sin^2 x + 5 \cos^2 x}
=\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x + 4 \cos^2 x}
=\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1 + 4 \cos^2 x}$$

From here, divide the top and bottom by $\cos^2 x$:

$$I = \int \frac{\sec^2 x \, \mathrm{d} x}{\sec^2 x + 4}= \int \frac{\sec^2 x \, \mathrm{d} x}{\sec^2 x -1+5}= \int \frac{\sec^2 x \, \mathrm{d} x}{\tan^2 x + 5}$$

Then $u=\tan x$ gives $\mathrm{d}u = \sec^2 x \, \mathrm{d} x$ and

$$I = \int \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2 + 5}$$

This is a fairly standard integral to solve with the substitution $u = \tan \theta$, or with a standard antiderivative,

$$\int \frac{\mathrm{d}\xi}{1+\xi^2} = \arctan \xi + C$$